# Trouble implementing a (stable) method of retrieving n bytes from file

Tags: c, io, stdio, file-handling

One of the purposes of the library of which I am developing is to retrieve a specified amount of bytes from a file, in this specific case I am wishing for access to */dev/random* to retrieve entropy based random sequences.

My main issue with fread is that it will hang indefinitely when waiting for more entropy, and this is unwanted. My next choice would have been wrapping fread with feof to take bytes in chunks, then I could at least provide percentages complete for a better experience, although from what I could gather iteration 1, 2, 3, 4..'s bytes will be hard to track to equal exactly the amount needed.

Is there a method in a C standard that allows for what I am looking for, exact amount wanted and in chunks? If I were to look for timeouts of this, would threading the data request be a good option to look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define "standard". Do you mean the ISO C standard? POSIX? Linux standards base (LSB)? For POSIX, the [read](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/read.html) call lets you specify the size of the buffer that you are trying to read. You can use [pselect](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pselect.html) or [poll](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/poll.html) to determine if there are bytes available to be read, with a timeout instead of blocking. On Linux, it is possible to use the "FIONREAD" [ioctl](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/ioctl.html) call to obtain the exact number of bytes available for reading.

That said, you should ask yourself if you need that level of entropy. You might (or might not) be able to get away with reading from "/dev/urandom". Of course, you would have to determine if that is the case.

Comment: Assuming the last parameter in the ioctl call is to pass a reference to an integer `ioctl(fd,FIONREAD,&unread);`, it claims /dev/random contains 3213910956 available bytes ( a bit odd ), I will try my luck with read again which seems to do a lot better than fread and I do like the pselect/poll options.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Here is the man page for a function I think will solve your problem.

http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fgets/

I just saw that fread wasnt working, fgets reads a certain number of byes from file stream into buffer

Comment: I am not entirely sure this would improve things, as in my case of reading unsigned chars, it will be 1, 1 or 1 either way with fread.