# How to make sure all the output on a pipe with async IO finished before closing

Tags: c, linux, unix

I use a pipe to read the output of a function by passing it a file descriptor. To read the output asynchronously I setup the "read" end of the pipe in ASYNC NON BLOCKING mode and I configure an IO handler using SIGACTION. My code looks like the following:

```
struct sigaction io_act;
struct sigaction io_act_old;
sigset_t block_mask;

/* create the pipe */    
pipe (pipe_fd);

/* set the reading end of pipe in ASYNC mode */
fcntl (pipe_fd[0], F_SETOWN, getpid());
fcntl (pipe_fd[0], F_SETFL, O_ASYNC | O_NONBLOCK);

/* add an I/O handler for SIGIO */
sigemptyset (&block_mask);
io_act.sa_handler = sigio_handler;
io_act.sa_mask = block_mask;
io_act.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
sigaction (SIGIO, &io_act, &io_act_old);

/* executing the function that generate output in given FILEDES */
my_generate_output (pipe_fd[1]);

close(pipe_fd[1]);

/* this sleep should not be needed (subject of question) */
sleep(1);
close (pipe_fd[0]);

/* restore previous signal handler */
sigaction (SIGIO, &io_act_old, NULL);
```

The problem is that if I omit the sleep function call I can close the pipe and disable the SIGIO handler before the output is completed. The consequence is that the application abort due to an unhandled SIGIO signal (message "I/O possible").

How can I make sure that all the output have been read from the pipe before disabling the SIGIO handler ?

Comment: Is the output to the pipe generated in a separate process or thread?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about this, but can't you `F_SETOWN` to 0 to prevent the signal?

Comment: Does aio_suspend() not give you what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the number of readable bytes, you might use the [`ioctl`](http://www.huihoo.org/gnu/linux/syscalls_17.html) `FIONREAD`, which is not very portable. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535030/linux-ioctl-fionread-returning-0-bytes-available-at-dev-random) as a contrived example.

You can also test availability of things to read with [poll](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll), [select](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) and friends.

And the end-of-file condition is reported with `read` returning 0 as count.

**ADDENDA**

according to [read(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read) syscall man page, `read` fails with errno ==:

```
   EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK
          The  file  descriptor  fd refers to a socket and has been marked
          nonblocking   (O_NONBLOCK),   and   the   read   would    block.
          POSIX.1-2001  allows  either error to be returned for this case,
          and does not require these constants to have the same value,  so
          a portable application should check for both possibilities.
```

Comment: This won't work. His file descriptors are set to non-blocking, meaning there's no way to differentiate between EOF and nothing to read at this moment. Also, `poll` and `select` won't block on a non-blocking file descriptor.

Comment: nothing available to read gives -1 from read with EWOULDBLOCK, but EOF gives 0 from read. And poll or select won't report as readable a non-blocking pipe or socket without available data (I did try a couple of years ago).

Comment: ioctl with FIONREAD seems to be fine, thanks. I cannot use the "read" method because I cannot consume output. I don't know about poll, I'm not familiar with it, I will study the man page :-)

Comment: **`poll` or `select`** (& friends) are **tremendously useful with non blocking reads**. You really can't avoid using them!

Answer (score -1):

I believe you cannot know if there will ever be more data in the pipe. So, if you control the process which is writing in to the pipe, you'll need to write an agreed-upon "END-OF-DATA" special sequence of bytes so that the reader knows when to stop.

Comment: There is no way to "flush" the pipe ? After all I know that the function that generate output have terminated.

Comment: Calling poll (or perhaps ioctl FIONREAD) or select to test that something is readable is always possible. And the end-of-file condition is reported by `read` (as a 0 byte count)

Comment: Well, according to `pipe(7)`, if all file descriptors for the write end have been closed, `read()` will see EOF and return 0. But, since your `read()` calls are nonblocking, I think there's no way to differentiate between EOF and no data available at the moment.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: `read` will also return 0 if there's no data *at the moment* for a nonblocking file descriptor.

Comment: This is not what the read man page says. See citation in edited answer. Pipes are practically like socketpairs so behave in that respect as sockets.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Whoops, that was my mistake. Thanks for the pointer to the documentation.

Comment: @tdenniston AFAIK, `read` sets `errno` to `EAGAIN` for EOF on non-blocking file descriptor.